# Can I put a large Ada program in an embedded system?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, ada

I would like to know whether a large Ada program I work with could run on a microprocessor or microcontroller because I'm exploring the possibility of implementing it in a dedicated package with low power requirements.

The program is over 500 source files in Ada 95, compiles in Win XP to a 10MB executable, and uses up to 200MB of memory running.  It does not require multiple threads, and does not need to run in "real time".

Does this even make sense for a program of this size?  If so, what are the options for operating systems?  Would the modifications to the code be extensive to make it compatible with an OS?

Comment: That'd have to be one heck of a microcontroller. Probably more realistic to go for an old/cheap x86 machine...

What exactly is it for?

Comment: Can your embedded system handle those requirements? I mean, you've provided zero details with which anyone could help; you don't state your OS, your Ada, system specs, whether there's a HW interface library callable from Ada (if you need the hardware), so who knows.

Comment: @Luke - Thanks for your quick response to my first question. This program is our main product in a very narrow field, so I can't really give more information about its purpose.

Comment: @ChipR - If you can't give informations, then it makes no sense to ask such a question.

Comment: @DaveNewton The embedded system doesn't exist. I don't have any OS or hardware limitations.

Comment: @ChipR Then sure, it'll work great.

Comment: @jeb What kind of information is needed?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't believe that answers any of my questions, but thanks.

Comment: @ChipR Perfect; I don't believe you've really asked a question. If you have no OS or hardware limitations, then you can run it as-is, and put Windows on the embedded system.

Comment: As Dave stated, if you haven't any limitations it's obviously that it could run. Take any big sized embedded system (ex. 64GB Ram, 10TB Disk) with any OS (CMX, Sciopta, Windows,Linux, OS/2) and be happy

Comment: I should have used "requirements" instead of "limitations".  My question was really about what my options were for embedded systems with low power consumption.  I will have to find a frame of reference for low power consumption, though.

Comment: You could try something like a Raspberry Pi or if that is too small a Beagleboard (these are ARM based boards about as powerful as a smartphone), with the GNU Ada compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good chance a lot of that large size you are currently seeing has to do with things the program requires in order to run on a big fat OS like XP.

Of course it could be that your program actually relies on a bunch of huge arrays or something, and there's no way it will fit. I can't really say from out here.

If it were me, I'd contact my Ada vendor for the platform I'm considering and ask for their help with a feasibility study. Generally licenses for Ada compilers on embedded targets run into enough dough that a vendor would be happy to give you some individual pre-sale attention like this.

One further thing I should mention. Ada has a very extensive runtime library. It includes among other things a full-on tasking and task synchronization kernel. Programs on "big fat OSes" like Windows or Linux often get to pull that stuff in, even if they don't need it. Most compilers provide a way to trim out the crud you don't need, and compilers on small embedded targets *have* to do that of course. So its possible a lot of that size will go away by itself if you build targeting a smaller platform. If you like, you can look over [Gnat's instructions for minimizing its runtime overhead](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat-hie-docs/html/gnathie_ug_5.html). Even if that isn't your vendor, it should show you some of the issues that are likely to be involved.

Comment: That makes sense, but how do I pick a platform?

Comment: @ChipR - I could be wrong, but my guess is you will be somewhat constrained by what platforms are available as Ada compiler targets (and of course what exactly are your "low power requirements", etc.) Again, you will probably need to talk to your vendor(s).

Comment: Yeah.. 10MB of code is a *lot* for a single-threaded app with a reasonable-size GUI.  Surely, there is something else in there - a load of internationalization resource files, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a reasonable fit for a Raspberry-Pi, which has Gnat as part of its Debian (Raspbian) distribution. You might have to pay attention to its memory footprint if that 200MB footprint is just the data...